# Figure out the time in millis for alarm

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am making a simple alarm clock application that mimics the default alarm app that comes with Android Lollipop.

The `set*( )` methods of an `AlarmManager` require the date on which the alarm should be fired as a Unix epoch.

The UI is rather simple with a `TimePicker`.

So, given the current time and the time the user has selected from `TimePicker`, how do I figure out the time in milliseconds when the alarm should be fired?

**Update:**
There are two cases I run into:

*Selecting the time that is after the current time*:
Assume it is 11am and the user selects the time from the time picker as 03pm. In this case, I know that the alarm should be scheduled for the same day.

*Selecting the time that is before the current time:*
Assume it is 11am and the user selects the time from the time picker as 10am. In this case, I know that the alarm should be scheduled for the **next day**'s 10am.

Answer (score 3):

Ok here you go:

```
// Get the current time
final Date currentTime = new Date();

// Set the hours and minutes from the time picker against todays date
final Calendar selectedTime = Calendar.getInstance();
selectedTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourFromTimePicker);
selectedTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteFromTimePicker);

// If the current date is greater than the hour and minute from time picker add one day
if (currentTime.getTime() > selectedTime.getTime().getTime()) {
    selectedTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}

// Schedule the alarm
//AlarmManager.set(selectedTime.getTime().getTime());
```

Comment: If [`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) gave time in millis, it'd be easy. However, it gives the time as just an hour and minute that the user has selected. I believe the solution would be more involved. :)

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about that. The second piece of code points you in the correct path then. Get a calendar for today and then set the hour and minute. I'll update again :)

Comment: @LittleChild ok completely working and self documenting now

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `android.text.format.Time` class

call the setters on the Time class to set the Hour, Minute, Second, etc. The Hours are in 24H time, so if the `current hour > selected hour` then you know to increment `days` by 1

Finally, call `Time#toMillis(boolean ignoreDst)` to get the system time in millis, and pass that to `AlarmManager`

EDIT: GregorianCalendar should be used instead.

Comment: Deprecated. Use `GregorianCalendar` instead :)

Comment: ah. would have seen that if I had an IDE in front of me ;p

Answer (score 0):

if you store data in java Date object:

```
long getTime( )
```

Returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970.just subtract.

Another way if you look only at time within day:

```
int ms = 1000*SECONDS + 1000*60*MINUTES + 1000*60*60*HOURS
```